# date:invalid date on converting user input to datetime shell

Tags: bash, shell, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a user input to datetime value but it gives invalid date error in shell script

```
start_time=$5' '$6
start_time=$(date --date='$start_time')
```

$5 the user is entering 03/12/2015
$6 the user is entering 00:10:00

Comment: The variable isn't expanded in single quotes. Try with double quotes like `--date="$start_time"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable expansion/substitution doesn't happen with single quotes. So in :

```
start_time=$(date --date='$start_time')
```

`$start_time` is not substituted with its content.

However, when you use double quotes variables are first substituted before doing anything with the resultant string. So do :

```
start_time=$(date --date="$start_time")
```

Comment: It was just an explanation to the comment by  @user000001 . Good things work for you anyway.